# How to Create Snapshot Backups in MySQL

Tags: mysql, backup, snapshot

I've seen a lot of people talking about snapshots backup, even I'm reading a book about mysql but nobody explain the code how to make a snapshots backup.  This is what the book says:

1. `flush tables with read lock`
2. take a snapshot
3. `unlock tables;`

THAT's SO NULL!....

Can someone give me MORE information about the snapshots in MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

I have written posts of this nature before

- [How can I optimize a mysqldump of a large database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-can-i-optimize-a-mysqldump-of-a-large-database/2227#2227)
- [recover a single mysql database on a busy master-slave replicated system](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10970/recover-a-single-mysql-database-on-a-busy-master-slave-replicated-system/10989#10989)
- [Set up a MySQL slave using mysqldump to get the initial data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8759/set-up-a-mysql-slave-using-mysqldump-to-get-the-initial-data/8780#8780)

You will find code samples and additional advice on its usage

I shy away from Snapshots as done by LVM if

- 90%+ Data is InnoDB
- innodb_file_per_table is disabled
- All Data Exceeds 200GB
- Heavy Write, Heavy Read

I wrote about this before : [Ibdata usage and Recommendations?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13614/ibdata-usage-and-recommendations/13638#13638)

While my personal preference is mysqldumps, if you have a small data volume, LVM snapshots would be just fine. If you are running MySQL 5.0/5.1, I would recommend running

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 0;
```

to flush up to 99% of the InnoDB Buffer Pool before performing a file-system snapshot. Then, set it back to

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 90;
```

This is not required for MySQL 5.5

An in-between solution would be [**Percona's XtraBackup**](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup/). Percona XtraBackup is free, open-source, and GPL